# TYPO3 Flexforms: Access previous set value

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I'd like to display forms per agency. To achieve this, I want to select one agency on the frontend plugin (with a flexform) and then, when I have chosen one, the flexform reloads with`<onChange>reload</onChange>` so I get the filtered records.

**Problem**

How can I access flexform-values in another select-block? My general idea is to use the `<foreign_table_where></foreign_table_where>` part to limit this. But I cant access previous set values (unlike I do it in the `<displayCond></displayCond>` block with FIELD:mySetting). My form-part looks like this:

**Form**

```
                     <config>
                            <type>select</type>
                            <foreign_table>foreignTableForm</foreign_table>
                            <foreign_table_where>HOW TO DO?</foreign_table_where>
                            <minitems>0</minitems>
                            <maxitems>10</maxitems>
                            <multiple>0</multiple>
                            <size>5</size>
                            <itemListStyle>Width:250px</itemListStyle>
                     </config>
```

**Agency**

```
                      <config>
                            <type>select</type>
                            <foreign_table>foreignTableAgency</foreign_table>
                            <minitems>0</minitems>
                            <maxitems>10</maxitems>
                            <multiple>0</multiple>
                            <size>5</size>
                            <itemListStyle>Width:250px</itemListStyle>
                        </config>
```

**Goal**

1. Get values from agency foreign table (works)
2. As I have clicked on that specific agency, the flexform reloads (works)
3. Only those forms get listed, which have the foreign key equal to the agency's uid previously set after the reload (how to achieve this?)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a hook to modify the flexform in the fly. Please check ext:news on how to archive this. It does something similar to trim the flexform to only show valid field in the current selected context.

Comment: You could do this. This is not what I meant, but it is properly easier to archive.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check, but it is already working with that itemsProcFunc.